# Sentry JS: How do I wait to load js until external file is loaded?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, sentry

I have Sentry installed on my website but I want to make it load asynchronously. I've tried adding `async` to the script tag that loads `bundle.tracing.min.js` but line `Sentry.init({` throws error `Uncaught ReferenceError: Sentry is not defined`

How can I run the JS after the `bundle.tracing.min.js` has loaded?

```js
//I WANT THIS CODE TO RUN AFTER THE ABOVE SCRIPT HAS FINISHED LOADING.
Sentry.init({
  dsn: "https://xxxxxxxxx@aaaaaa.ingest.sentry.io/111111",
  release: "test@1.0",
  integrations: [new Sentry.Integrations.BrowserTracing()],
  tracesSampleRate: 0.1,
});
```

```html
<script src="https://browser.sentry-cdn.com/6.11.0/bundle.tracing.min.js" integrity="sha384-XuDodzzzzzzF6ES/zzzzz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where you got that script src from, but [the Sentry doc](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/install/cdn/) says you can use the below one, which works fine and doesn't produce an "Uncaught ReferenceError: Sentry is not defined" error.

Just make sure you put the cdn script tag before your script in your html file.

```js
//I WANT THIS CODE TO RUN AFTER THE ABOVE SCRIPT HAS FINISHED LOADING.
Sentry.init({
  dsn: "https://xxxxxxxxx@aaaaaa.ingest.sentry.io/111111",
  release: "test@1.0",
  integrations: [new Sentry.Integrations.BrowserTracing()],
  tracesSampleRate: 0.1,
});
```

```html
<script
  src="https://browser.sentry-cdn.com/6.16.1/bundle.tracing.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-hySah00SvKME+98UjlzyfP852AXjPPTh2vgJu26gFcwTlZ02/zm82SINaKTKwIX2"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
></script>
```